# VScode $workspaceRoot variable is not being resolved

Tags: visual-studio-code, rubocop

I trying to configure my .rubocop.yml file for my workspace throught the configFilePath of the rubocop plugin, but the vscode is not resolving the variable ${workspaceRoot}.

This NOT works:

```
"ruby.rubocop.configFilePath": "${workspaceRoot}\\.rbenv\\.rubocop.yml"
```

This works:

```
"ruby.rubocop.configFilePath": "C:\\Users\\My_User\\My_Project\\.rbenv\\.rubocop.yml"
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, I just made a fork of the plugin and fixed that for me.

Comment: @Teather Can you please post your fork link here

Comment: @Hrishi I made it locally and the code stayed on my old company's computer, sorry =/

Comment: @Teather: No problem, could you point me to code, I will try to fix it. If you find free time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the extension to look in the working dir you could also do:

```
"ruby.rubocop.configFilePath": "/.rubocop.yml"
```